# login error "cannot convert implicitly void to string"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a login page with the following code:

PROCEDURE:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Login_Validation]

@email varchar(100),
@password varchar(50)

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @cnt INTEGER
SET @cnt = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SUBSCRIBER_MASTER WHERE EmailId=@email AND [Password]=@password AND [Status]='Y')

END
```

class file:

```
public void Login_Validation(string email, string password)
{

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString);
try
{
    LocalConnection_Class(con);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Login_Validation", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100)).Value = email;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)).Value = password;
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.HasRows)
    {
        dr.Read();
    }

    cmd.Dispose();
    con.Close();
}
catch (Exception)
{ }
}
```

cs file:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string login = obj.Login_Validation(txtEmail.Text, txtPassword.Text);
}
```

I am not able to understand how to solve the error. Can someone help me out?
It's giving me an error: "Cannot convert implicitly void to string at obj.Login_Validation".

Comment: That error is straight forward.. you need to change that method signature to have a return as well as a return type of `string`

Comment: `Please state what that stored procedure returns as well you are missing code in your conditional check and or after

Comment: What are you expecting `Login_Validation` to return?

Comment: Look below it shall speak for itself..

Comment: @asawyer Common Sense is all the evidence one needs here ..look at the question and look at the posted answers and tell me that all of them are incorrect..LOL `I THINK NOT`

Comment: @DJKRAZE I'm not saying there wasn't a serial downvoter here, I'm saying there's no evidence it was the OP, and this question is not spam. Low effort/quality sure, but not spam.

Comment: anyway.. if you read the question yourself I want you to tell me what the fix is based on his title and his stating about the error we are all answering the question based off of the reported error not the running / executing of his stored procedure which has some flaws but that was not the `Reported Error / Issue` you are free to help this OP I am done with the correspondence in this regard..

Answer (score 0):

Like **DJ KRAZE** told you

your `string login = obj.Login_Validation(txtEmail.Text, txtPassword.Text);` suggested your Method `Login_Validation` will return a string so you need to do 2 things

First
change your method header 
`public void Login_Validation(string email, string password)` to 
`public string Login_Validation(string email, string password)`

Secound 
now you need to add an return in your method

for example

```
public string Login_Validation(string email, string password)
    {
        //...

        try
        {
            //...

            return //<- your string if succeed
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { 
            return //<- your string if an error occurs
        }

        // or you place just one return here
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You declared a function as void, `public void Login_Validation` and are trying to assign a string from that.

That's not going to work, and the error message is very clear on that.

Change the method signature to return a string, and add a return statement with the relevent data from the stored procedure.

Edit - Actually your stored procedure doesn't seem to return anything. Start there!
Maybe an output parameter.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Login_Validation]

@email varchar(100),
@password varchar(50),
@isValid bit outbit 
AS
BEGIN


SET @isValid = EXISTS(SELECT * FROM SUBSCRIBER_MASTER WHERE EmailId=@email AND [Password]=@password AND [Status]='Y')

END
```

Answer (score -1):

Your Login_Validation doesn't return anything. It returns a 'void'.

If you want it to return something, change the signature to return a string.

```
public string Login_Validation
```

then return whatever you want.

Answer (score -1):

Try this for use SqlDataReader   instead of void

```
public SqlDataReader  Login_Validation(string email, string password)
{
   SqlConnection con = new     SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString);
    LocalConnection_Class(con);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Login_Validation", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100)).Value = email;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)).Value = password;
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
    cmd.Dispose();
    con.Close();
    return dr ;
}
```

And call this way for

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
SqlDataReader   login = obj.Login_Validation(txtEmail.Text, txtPassword.Text);

if(login.HasRows)
{
//Login Successfully 
}
else
{
//Login Failed
}
}
```